# Magento 1.7 : Custom Option Validation Dependent on another Custom Option

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, validation, dropdown-attribute, dependency

I need help to **apply validation on custom option**, that is dependent on another custom option value.

Here is the image, which describes what I actually want :

[image]

Please suggest, I am using **Custom Options**, **Not Configurable Products**